# Should I use GA4 or firebase to configure my app?

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I have added my app to GA4 using data streams. It seems it is associated with a firebase project id. But the project doesn't appear in the "Your apps" section of the Firebase console. If I add my app in Firebase section, it generated a different project id.
So is it necesssary to configure both?

Answer (score 0):

In the Firebase console I got somehow two projects with the same name.
It seems that when creating a GA4 property, it will also create the project in the Firebase console.
To answer my own question, when creating a "data stream" for an app, it will automatically add the app to the Firebase console. If not, that because you are in the wrong project.

I guess that if I had added the app to the Firebase console first, it would have been added to the "Data Streams" section for the GA4 also. (As long as the Firebase project is linked to the GA4 property though)